# Django contact form confirmation email

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm relatively new to django and building my first app.

Tried searching through the site, but for the life of me cannot find the relevant information needed.

I'm looking to have a confirmation email sent to the entered email address on a contact form. I've seen examples of sending to a chosen address, or to user, but I can't seem to work out how to send mail to the email entered on the form.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Quote(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="your name")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

`forms.py`:

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
```

`views.py`:

```
class QuoteView(CreateView):
    model = Quote
    form_class = QuoteForm
    template_name = "quote/quote.html"
    success_url = "/quote/success/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super(QuoteView,self).form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

class QuoteSuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "quote/quote-complete.html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access validated form data (coerced to the fields respective types) via the `cleaned_data` attribute as shown in the form docs 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def form_valid(self, form):
    super(QuoteView,self).form_valid(form)
    send_mail("Foo", "bar", 'from@example.com', [form.cleaned_data['email']])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.